# Ignoring invalid SSL certificates on Cordova for Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, ssl

I have a cordova application that is using an invalid SSL certificate.

In  3.3.6 I could override the SSL certificate by extending the org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient and overriding the method public void onReceivedSslError, i.e.

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;

import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MyWebViewClient extends CordovaWebViewClient {

    public MyWebViewClient(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView view) {
        super(cordova, view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError
    (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }

}
```

And then from the starting Java file I could use

```
MyWebViewClient myWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient(this, this.appView);
this.appView.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
```

After upgrading to 5.2.2 I can't use something like that as the WebView has been changed to Crosswalk. What I have tried based on the guidelines of [Ignoring invalid SSL certificates on Cordova for Android and iOS](http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/), is to change the code above as following:

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewClient;
import org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class myWebViewClient extends SystemWebViewClient {

    public myWebViewClient(SystemWebViewEngine systemWebViewEngine) {

        super(systemWebViewEngine);
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError
    (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {


            handler.proceed();
        }

    }
```

And in the code calling:

```
CordovaActivity ca = (CordovaActivity) this.cordovaInterface.getActivity();
SystemWebView view = (SystemWebView) appView.getView();
myWebViewClient cWebClient = new myWebViewClient((SystemWebViewEngine) appView.getEngine());
appView.clearCache();
view.setWebViewClient(cWebClient);
```

However I receive the following exception

```
Unknown error during webview in activity
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView cannot be cast to org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView
    at myProject.InitApp.onCreate(initApp.java:182)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Any help on that? It seems as if the Crosswalk doesn't allow such overriding. Is there any way to override it?

Comment: I'm following your instructions in the linked article . Im overriding onReceiveSSLErrors() on SystemWebViewClient.java. You cannot cast XWalkCordovaView (extends from xwalkView its core project) to SystemWebViewClient (extends webviewclient its android class). I think you should follow the instructions, and override the method onREceiveSSLErros() not extend class SystemWebViewClient

Comment: Yes...I'm checking the code as well. It's an interface and as a consequence it cannot be cast. However I've tried to change the code and when I debug it from Android Studio it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not so sure if it's compiled or Android Studio takes something else...

Comment: I'm working on it too. Im found a clue about that, I'm trying to override XwalkCordovaResourceClient.java with the same logic. But it is true that it seems that not compile those classes. If I can fix it I will comment on here

Comment: If you have this problem working with inapp browser , I suggest try iframe inside cordova html page . It  ignores the SSL error .

Comment: My problem was the server certificate it`s not considered trusted by Android system. The code its fine.

Comment: Anybody find a solution? Seems like XWalkCordovaResourceClient.java is the place to do it...